# How do I delete/replace a file from an image field

Tags: python, django

how do I delete/replace an old file when a new file is uploaded. For example, if a user upload profile picture(img1), then if the same user upload a new profile picture(img2), (img1) will be deleted/replace with (img2). But when I try uploading a new picture it duplicate to a new row in database and the picture display multiple times on template.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', blank=True)

def home(request):
    profile_img = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)



{% for pic in profile_img %}
{% if pic.profile_pic %} 
<img src="{{ pic.profile_pic.url }}">
{% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In the view that lets the user upload the image, you should fetch the existing `Profile` objects and update that instead of creating a new one. Also maybe change the `user` relation to a one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

To update the image you need to update the profile_pic value, use below in your view to update:

```
profile_img = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).update(profile_pic=<NEW_VALUE>)
```

Comment: What should be added in the NEW_VALUE?

Comment: New value should be the url of the image. Once you update the url of image, you can render the page and display the image from the updated URL.

Comment: @Anupam..thank you. But I use another method, I will post the method I use.

Comment: I am having a problem in my model, in my model profile_pic I added default='/static/images/pic. jpg' as the default image, but the image do not display on template. Is there an error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, just add this in POST method:

```
m, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user )
m.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic'] 
m.save()
```